# How to exclude table in Entity Framework. Or simply include table which I want to return

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm new to Web API and Entity Framework.

I want to return a list of customers from my `DbContext` class, but the problem is, it returns a list of customers as well as all the `Orders`, `CustomerDemographics`, `OrderDetails` etc, which I don't want.

I want a list of only customers - that's it.

So how to exclude such unwanted tables in Entity Framework?

This is my code:

```
public List<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
    var customers = db.Customers;
    return customers.ToList();
}
```

Comment: show your entity model structure

Comment: hey .. I found solution to this.I added following line to my action and it worked...  db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;